# Placing Image in the Center of a Sunburst Chart with D3.js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, sunburst-diagram

I am almost done making a zoomable sunburst chart and the last thing I want to do is to place an image in the center.  I have checked other stackoverflow questions, but I have not been able to find a workable solution as I am not very experienced with D3.js or svg graphics.
I have included an image property in the JSON file I am using, but the center is the only location I want an image.  So I have been thinking that it will be better to simply place the image in the center of the canvas drawn by D3.js
If anyone has any suggestions or idea's on how to solve this problem I would be greatly appreciative, thank you.

[image: Here is an image of the chart]

Here is the image property in the JSON file:

```
{
 "name": "Wine Aroma Wheel",
 "description": "The Davis Wine Aroma Wheel is divided into several sections to help you visualize the different flavors, scents and aromatic qualities found in most red and white wines, regardless of the grape variety.  The same aromatic complexities and sensations pictured on the wine aroma wheel are found in red and white wines all over the world, from Bordeaux, to California and the Rhone Valley, as well as every other viticultural area.",
 "image": "images/Grape-2.jpg",
 "children": [
  {
. . .
```

Here is my CSS3 code:

```
circle,
path {
  cursor: pointer;
}

circle {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;  
}

#tooltip { background-color: white;
              padding: 3px 5px;
              border: 1px solid black;
              text-align: center;}

html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Here is the JavaScript code for the sunburst chart:

```
var margin = {top: 650, right: 650, bottom: 650, left: 650},
    radius = Math.min(margin.top, margin.right, margin.bottom, margin.left) - 168;

function filter_min_arc_size_text(d, i) {return (d.dx*d.depth*radius/1)>14};

var hue = d3.scale.category10();

var luminance = d3.scale.sqrt()
    .domain([0, 1e6])
    .clamp(true)
    .range([80, 20]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.name, b.name); })
    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx - .01 / (d.depth + .5); })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return (radius + 6) / 3 * d.depth; })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return (radius + 6) / 3 * (d.depth + 1.) - 1; });

//Tooltip description
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("id", "tooltip")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "10")
    .style("opacity", 0);

function format_number(x) {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}


function format_description(d) {
  var description = d.description;
      return  '<b>' + d.name + '</b></br>'+ d.description + '<br> (' + format_number(d.value) + ')';
}

function computeTextRotation(d) {
    var rotation = (d.x + d.dx / 2) * 180 / Math.PI - 90;
    return {
        global: rotation,
        correction: rotation > 90 ? 180 : 0
    };
}

function isRotated(d) {
    var rotation = (d.x + d.dx / 2) * 180 / Math.PI - 90;
    return rotation > 90 ? true : false
}

function mouseOverArc(d) {
             d3.select(this).attr("stroke","black")
          tooltip.html(format_description(d));
          return tooltip.transition()
            .duration(50)
            .style("opacity", 0.9);
        }

function mouseOutArc(){
    d3.select(this).attr("stroke","")
    return tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
}

function mouseMoveArc (d) {
          return tooltip
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px")
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");
}

var root_ = null;
d3.json("data/davis-aroma-wheel.json", function(error, root) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error);
  // Compute the initial layout on the entire tree to sum sizes.
  // Also compute the full name and fill color for each node,
  // and stash the children so they can be restored as we descend.

  partition
      .value(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .nodes(root)
      .forEach(function(d) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.sum = d.value;
        d.key = key(d);
        d.fill = fill(d);
      });

  // Now redefine the value function to use the previously-computed sum.
  partition
      .children(function(d, depth) { return depth < 3 ? d._children : null; })
      .value(function(d) { return d.sum; });

  var center = svg.append("circle")
      .attr("r", radius / 3)
      .on("click", zoomOut);

  center.append("title")
      .text("Zoom Out");


  var partitioned_data = partition.nodes(root).slice(1)

  var path = svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(partitioned_data)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.fill; })
      .each(function(d) { this._current = updateArc(d); })
      .on("click", zoomIn)
          .on("mouseover", mouseOverArc)
      .on("mousemove", mouseMoveArc)
      .on("mouseout", mouseOutArc);

  var texts = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(partitioned_data)
      .enter().append("text")
          .filter(filter_min_arc_size_text)
      .attr("transform", function(d) 
        {
          var r = computeTextRotation(d);
          return "rotate(" + r.global + ")"
            + "translate(" + radius / 3. * d.depth + ")"
            + "rotate(" + -r.correction + ")";
        })
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("dx", function(d) {return isRotated(d) ? "-85" : "85"}) //margin
      .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
      .on("click", zoomIn)
          .text(function(d,i) {return d.name})

  function zoomIn(p) {
    if (p.depth > 1) p = p.parent;
    if (!p.children) return;
    zoom(p, p);
  }

  function zoomOut(p) {
    if (!p.parent) return;
    zoom(p.parent, p);
  }

  // Zoom to the specified new root.
  function zoom(root, p) {
    if (document.documentElement.__transition__) return;

    // Rescale outside angles to match the new layout.
    var enterArc,
        exitArc,
        outsideAngle = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

    function insideArc(d) {
      return p.key > d.key
          ? {depth: d.depth - 1, x: 0, dx: 0} : p.key < d.key
          ? {depth: d.depth - 1, x: 2 * Math.PI, dx: 0}
          : {depth: 0, x: 0, dx: 2 * Math.PI};
    }

    function outsideArc(d) {
      return {depth: d.depth + 1, x: outsideAngle(d.x), dx: outsideAngle(d.x + d.dx) - outsideAngle(d.x)};
    }

    center.datum(root);

    // When zooming in, arcs enter from the outside and exit to the inside.
    // Entering outside arcs start from the old layout.
    if (root === p) enterArc = outsideArc, exitArc = insideArc, outsideAngle.range([p.x, p.x + p.dx]);

     var new_data=partition.nodes(root).slice(1)

    path = path.data(new_data, function(d) { return d.key; });

     // When zooming out, arcs enter from the inside and exit to the outside.
    // Exiting outside arcs transition to the new layout.
    if (root !== p) enterArc = insideArc, exitArc = outsideArc, outsideAngle.range([p.x, p.x + p.dx]);

    d3.transition().duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750).each(function() {
      path.exit().transition()
          .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.depth === 1 + (root === p) ? 1 : 0; })
          .attrTween("d", function(d) { return arcTween.call(this, exitArc(d)); })
          .remove();

      path.enter().append("path")
        .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return d.depth === 2 - (root === p) ? 1 : 0; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d.fill; })
        .on("click", zoomIn)
              .on("mouseover", mouseOverArc)
        .on("mousemove", mouseMoveArc)
        .on("mouseout", mouseOutArc)
        .each(function(d) { this._current = enterArc(d); });


      path.transition()
          .style("fill-opacity", 1)
          .attrTween("d", function(d) { return arcTween.call(this, updateArc(d)); });

    });


     texts = texts.data(new_data, function(d) { return d.key; })

    texts.exit()
        .remove()
    texts.enter()
      .append("text")

    texts.style("opacity", 0)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        var r = computeTextRotation(d);
        return "rotate(" + r.global + ")" 
        + "translate(" + radius / 3 * d.depth + ",0)" 
        + "rotate(" + -r.correction + ")";
      })
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("dx", function(d) {return isRotated(d) ? "-85" : "85"}) //margin
      .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
      .filter(filter_min_arc_size_text)
      .on("click", zoomIn)
      .text(function(d,i) {return d.name})
          .transition().delay(750).style("opacity", 1)

  }
});

function key(d) {
  var k = [], p = d;
  while (p.depth) k.push(p.name), p = p.parent;
  return k.reverse().join(".");
}

function fill(d) {
  var p = d;
  while (p.depth > 1) p = p.parent;
  var c = d3.lab(hue(p.name));
  c.l = luminance(d.sum);
  return c;
}

function arcTween(b) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, b);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) {
    return arc(i(t));
  };
}

function updateArc(d) {
  return {depth: d.depth, x: d.x, dx: d.dx};
}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", margin.top + margin.bottom + "px");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use image element inside svg. ([Reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag))

Using d3 according with your code, it will be something like

```
svg.append("image").attr("xlink:href", "firefox.jpg")
    .attr("width", w).attr("height", h)
    .attr("x", -w/2).attr("y", -h/2)
```

Comment: Thank you Daniela, this example did not work but you did lead me to a solution.

Comment: Yes, it was just an example based on your code, you had to change the path of the image and assign the w and h properties based on your image size

Comment: I had a difficult time trying to get the image resized with the code, so I used photoshop to edit the image to fit

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this dilemma with the help of Daniela Mogini's suggestion.
I resized the canvas size of the grapes image to 1300x1300px with a transparent background, with the image of the grapes in the circle.

Then I added this cold below: var arc = d3.svg.arc()

```
svg.append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "images/grapes.png")
  .attr("x", -650)
  .attr("y", -650);
```